# Next Js App host with custom server on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to host my Next.js application (only Frontend) on AWS Amplify. I can achieve this using the Static site generation of Next.js.

I somehow have to use a custom server (server.js) and it also means that my start script would be like: `"start" : "node server.js"`
instead of `"start" : "next start"`.

I am facing a problem in serving my application amplify using this custom server.
I found an article about Next JS SSR with AWS Amplify, but it includes some backend as well, which is not included in my case.

How can I use Next.js custom server with AWS Amplify? or there is no way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that AWS Amplify did not support the SSR of Next.js until recently AWS provided the support for SSR for Next as well as Nuxt. [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/amplify-javascript-adds-server-side-rendering-support-frameworks-next-js-nuxt-js/) is the link to the documentation of SSR in AWS Amplify.